# Incrementing in Dr.Java

Tags: java

Write a RECURSIVE method 'countToBy' that takes two integer 
parameters n and m and that produces output indicating how 
to count to n in increments of m.

For example, to count to 10 by 1 you'd say:  countToBy(10, 1);
which should produce the following output:
     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

The increment does not have to be 1.  For example, the 
following call indicates that we want to count to 25 in 
increments of 4:   countToBy(25, 4);
which produces this output:
     1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25

---

My Code for this is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CountBy {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    countToBy(34, 5);
    System.out.println(); 
    countToBy(3, 6);
    System.out.println(); 
    countToBy(17, 3);
    System.out.println(); 
  }

  // *** Your printSorted method goes here ***
  public static void countToBy(int max, int var){
    if (max < var)
      System.out.print("Error, max value too low or skip value too high.");
      else{
        for (int x = var-1; x<=max; x = x + var){
          System.out.print(x + ", ");
}
    }
}
}
```

This works, but I feel like I am missing something... anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: Your method is not [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

Comment: `This works, but I feel like I am missing something... anyhelp would be appreciated.` You might want to try on codereview. Stackoverflow is for specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea how to write such recursive method:

```
public static void method(int x, int y){
        if(x<y) return;
        method(x-1, y);
        System.out.print(x + " ");      
}
```

This method prints sequence of number from `y` to `x`. So for `method(20,10);` it will print out: `10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test {
void counttoby(int n,int m,int aff){
    if(aff==n) System.out.println(n);
    else{
        if(n<aff) System.out.println("error");
        else{
        counttoby(n,m,aff+m);
        System.out.println(aff);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test t= new test();
    t.counttoby(10, 1,1);

}
```

}

try this code okay